# How to cover if-else in testclass

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

```
public class PED_WelcomeMessageController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getUserName() {
        return userinfo.getName();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getGreetingText(){
        User usr = [Select Contact.Codice_Fiscale__c from User where Id=:UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1];
        String sCodiceFiscale = usr.Contact.Codice_Fiscale__c;
        //String sGreetings = 'benvenuta';
        String sGreetings = Label.PED_WelcomeFemale;
        if(sCodiceFiscale != null){
            String sGenderCode = sCodiceFiscale.substring(9, 11);
            Integer iGenderCodeVal = Integer.valueof(sGenderCode.trim());            
            if(iGenderCodeVal < 40){
                //sGreetings = 'benvenuto';
                sGreetings = Label.PED_WelcomeMale;
            }
            else{
                //sGreetings = 'benvenuta';
                sGreetings = Label.PED_WelcomeFemale;
            }
        }
        return sGreetings;
    }
}
```

my test class is

```
@isTest
private class PED_WelcomeMessageController_Test{
  static testMethod void test_Method1(){
    PED_WelcomeMessageController obj01 = new PED_WelcomeMessageController();
    PED_WelcomeMessageController.getUserName();
  }
  static testMethod void test_Method2(){
    PED_WelcomeMessageController obj01 = new PED_WelcomeMessageController();
    PED_WelcomeMessageController.getGreetingText();
  }
}
```

above test class covering 61% but it is not covering

```
String sGenderCode = sCodiceFiscale.substring(9, 11);
Integer iGenderCodeVal = Integer.valueof(sGenderCode.trim());            
if(iGenderCodeVal < 40){
    //sGreetings = 'benvenuto';
    sGreetings = Label.PED_WelcomeMale;
}
else{
    //sGreetings = 'benvenuta';
    sGreetings = Label.PED_WelcomeFemale;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method.

Since your code inside the `if(sCodiceFiscale != null)` block is not being covered, that means that when you run your tests, `sCodiceFiscale` is equal to `null` (which means the code inside the if block is not being executed).

In the end, this comes down to the setup phase of your test, and [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). From that page (emphasis mine):

> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, **test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization**, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, **and can only access data that they create**. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage
>
> **Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test**.

`Contact` is not on that list, so if your code relies on a `User` being related to a `Contact`, you need to set that up yourself.

That may look something like this...

```
static testMethod void test_Method1(){
    // Phase 1 of unit testing, test setup
    // Good tests need to create (almost) all of their required data.
    // For this test, we want to test the greeting for a Male contact.
    Contact maleContact = new Contact(
        FirstName = 'John',
        LastName = 'Smith',
        Codice_Fiscale__c = 15 // Integer value < 40 = male
    );
    insert maleContact;

    // Now we need to associate the contact to the user running the test.
    // Users count as 'setup data', while a Contact is not.
    // We can't perform DML on normal data and setup data (you'll get a MIXED_DML
    //   exception if you do), so we need to use System.runAs() to work around that.
    User usr = new User(
        Id = UserInfo.getUserId(),
        ContactId = maleContact.Id
    );

    System.runAs(usr){
        update usr;
    }

    // Phase 2 of unit testing, test execution
    // Generally, this is where you'd use Test.startTest()/stopTest().
    // Using those isn't required, but it's a good habit to get into.
    // Using those gives the code, contained within, a new set of governor limits
    //   (which can be a lifesaver, since test setup always counts towards governor limits,
    //   and complex test setup can use a lot of queries/dml)

    PED_WelcomeMessageController obj01 = new PED_WelcomeMessageController();

    Test.startTest();
    // Capture the result of the method for later
    String result = PED_WelcomeMessageController.getUserName();
    Test.stopTest();

    // Phase 3 of unit testing, verification
    // I'd argue that a unit test isn't really a 'test' if you don't make assertions.
    // Assertions are how you verify that your code actually behaves the way you expect
    //   it to.
    // Without assertions, a test only tells you whether or not your code completed
    //   running or not.

    // assertEquals() and assertNotEquals() only require 2 parameters, but the 3 parameter
    //   version can be extremely helpful.
    // The third parameter is a string message that is printed when the assertion
    //   fails.
    // Including a specific message helps to identify exactly what went wrong, and
    //   can allow you to narrow down the problematic section of the code being tested
    //   without needing to look back at the test method.
    System.assertEquals(Label.PED_WelcomeMale, result, 'The resulting greeting was different than expected');

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Derek, for the great explanation. I am new into programming. Thanks a lot.